# Properties of relations (symmetry and anti-symmetry)

Tags: relations

I have read few question posted mathmatics, yet I am still confused... so I do understand this is quiet frequently asked.

If relation = {(1,1)} would this be anti-symmetric and symmetric? I do understand that symmetry means when (a,b) is in set (b,a) should also be in the set. in this case {(a,a),(a,a)} = {(a,a)} and it is also anti-symmetric since there is no another (a,a)?

I think I am contradicting my arguments for symmetry and anti-symmetry but I can't really find any good explanation why this can't be true

Comment: You "can't really find any good explanation why this can't be true" because it's true. It really is both symmetric and antisymmetric. So, *antisymmetric* does not mean or even imply *not symmetric*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation ${(1,1)}$ is symmetric because every $(a,b)$ has a matching $(b,a)$.  It is also anti-symmetric  because the only case where $(a,b) = (b,a)$ is when $ a = b$.

Comment: It's *antisemetic*, you say?

Comment: @BrianO damn typos.

Comment: Should've left it--would've given everyone a good laugh wondering how an ordered pair could be racist.